# "multiple definition of `memcmp" error when linking Rust staticlib with embedded C program

Tags: c, linker, rust, embedded, ffi

I have a Rust function I would like to call from a [C project](http://github.com/numworks/epsilon) that runs on an STM32F412 MCU, but I am getting a series of "multiple definition of" linker errors.

Here is my lib.rs:

```rust
#![crate_type = "staticlib"]
#![feature(lang_items)]
#![no_std]
#![no_builtins]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello_world(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}

#[lang = "eh_personality"] extern fn eh_personality() {}
#[lang = "panic_fmt"] fn panic_fmt() -> ! { loop {} }
```

Building with `cargo build --release --target=thumbv7em-none-eabihf` produces a `librust.a` which I added as an object to the C Makefile.

The complete list of linker errors can be [found here](https://pastebin.com/raw/bqiKyvTw). `nm` shows all the conflicting functions as global text symbols (T), [full output here](https://pastebin.com/raw/1MYBPCCq).

The C project does not have a normal standard C library, instead it uses a custom libc a device-specific implementation that covers a small portion of the standard. Can I tell the Rust library to use those functions?

Reading through the Rust features list, there is `#![feature(compiler_builtins_lib)]` but this does the exact opposite of what I want, for if you are getting "undefined reference to" linker errors.

Comment: can you post `nm librust.a` ? and your `Cargo.toml` ? And how do you link you program ?

Comment: I've added the output of nm and my Cargo.toml is as default except for "crate-type = ["staticlib"]". arm-none-eabi-ld is the linker, using ordinary Makefiles. The [flags are here](https://github.com/numworks/epsilon/blob/master/build/toolchain.arm-gcc.mak).

Comment: Can you share your complete linking command line? Also try swapping the order of your code and the Rust static library when linking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bunch of duplicated symbols coming from your customized "standard library" `liba` and from generated *builtin* symbols inserted into `librust.a`:

```
memset, memcpy, memmove, ecc, ecc
```

Your problem arises because the order of object files matters when linking.

If you put `librust.a` too early in the ordered sequence of files to link, then files before `librust.a` will resolve symbols from `librust.a` and files coming after `librust.a` will resolve the same symbols from `liba` and this generates duplicate symbol errors.

To avoid this problem, put the Rust library at the end of object files to link.

In epsilon Makefile change the link commands as:

```
RUST_LIB_DIR = <path_to_librust.a>

.SECONDARY: $(objs)
%.$(EXE):
    @echo "LD      $@"
    $(Q) $(LD) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -L$(RUST_LIB_DIR) -l:librust.a -o $@
```

This recipe links successfully on my side.
My basic `epsilon/apps/main.cpp` instrumentation:

```c
#include "global_preferences.h"
#include "apps_container_storage.h"

extern "C" int hello_world(int a, int b);

void ion_main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  hello_world(1,2);
  ...
```