# multiple definition of `__udivti3' in libgcc and Rust system library

Tags: rust, linkageerror

I am trying to link some executable (which compiled with gcc) with the library that is compiled with `cargo build`.

cargo generates both .a and .so libraries from the code written in Rust language.

The linkage error is:

```
/sharedhome/maxaxe01/mbed-cloud-client-example-internal/mbed-cloud-client/parsec-se-driver/target/debug/libparsec_tpm_direct_se_driver.a(compiler_builtins-2541f1e09df1c67d.compiler_builtins.dh9snxly-cgu.0.rcgu.o): In function `__udivti3':
/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/compiler_builtins-0.1.25/src/int/udiv.rs:247: multiple definition of `__udivti3'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a(_udivdi3.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I understand, the problem that some low level processor math function defined twice, in my libgcc and RUST system library compiler_builtins-0.1.25/src/int/udiv.rs  May be somebody has some idea how to solve this?

If I link executable with library as shared object, it is successfully linked, but I need to compile with static lib! (cargo build generates both, .so and .a)

This thread (["multiple definition of `memcmp" error when linking Rust staticlib with embedded C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433610/multiple-definition-of-memcmp-error-when-linking-rust-staticlib-with-embedded/50453432#50453432)) does not help me.

Comment: Any success on this? I'm having a very similar error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950040/multiple-definition-of-aeabi-ul2f-for-rust-c-mixed-code-on-android-libgcc

Answer (score 1):

If the two versions of the function `__udivti3` are equivalent, you could try linking your program with `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition`. This is obviously an ugly hack and I would be interested in getting a proper solution, but it worked for me. I was getting a similar conflict on `__muloti4` between the `compiler-builtins` crate (part of the standard library) and a static version of LLVM `libc++`.

Obviously, I am assuming that using a `cdylib` is not an option for you and your Rust library needs to be static.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here arises because you use `--whole-archive` option of linker for all linked libraries (which you should not). Please disable whole archive by `--no-whole-archive` after you are finished with linking your libraries.

For ex (in cmake).

```
target_link_libraries ( Mycomponent
                        PUBLIC -Wl,--whole-archive 
                        lib1.a lib2.a
                        -Wl,--no-whole-archive )
```

Detailed information about [--whole-archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52450099/19014254)